# Unable to create index in Elastic search using API

Tags: api, elasticsearch, indexing, kibana-5

I am trying to create index in Elasticsearch using API using the following mapping in kibana dev tools. Once I create the index, I want to use reindex API to copy documents from an already existing index.

```
        PUT /ipflow-logs
        {
          "ipflow-logs" : {
            "mappings" : {
              "properties" : {
                "conn_state" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "content_length" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "content_type" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "createdDate" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "dst_ip" : {
                  "type" : "ip"
                },
                "dst_port" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "duration" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "history" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "local_orig" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "missed_bytes" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "orig_bytes" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "orig_ip_bytes" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "orig_pkts" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "protocol" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "resp_bytes" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "resp_ip_bytes" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "resp_pkts" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "service" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "src_ip" : {
                  "type" : "ip"
                },
                "src_port" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "timestamp" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                },
                "uid" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I am getting the below error when I try to create the index.

"type": "parse_exception", "reason": "unknown key [ipflow-logs] for create index", "status": 400

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it this way (i.e. `mappings` should be at the top):

```
PUT /ipflow-logs
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "conn_state": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "content_length": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "content_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "dst_ip": {
        "type": "ip"
      },
      "dst_port": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "duration": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "history": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "local_orig": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "missed_bytes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "orig_bytes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "orig_ip_bytes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "orig_pkts": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "protocol": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "resp_bytes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "resp_ip_bytes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "resp_pkts": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "service": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "src_ip": {
        "type": "ip"
      },
      "src_port": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      },
      "uid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```